# Training data : forecasted or actual?

Tags: time-series, training, machine-learning-model, forecasting

I am working on a time series prediction problem. I am using keras models for machine learning.

For this prediction, weather variables are used as input. They can be of two types: forecasted and actual. I have acquired both these types of data of a considerable amount of time and I want to train and test my model on the data. My question is:

1) Should I use forecasted weather variables OR actual weather variables in input while training? (consider that only forecasted weather variables will be available at model inferencing time).

2) Same question 1 for testing.

Is there a rule or general practice regarding the above questions? If yes, I would like to know that.

Comment: What do you want to predict? Whether a given forecast will be right given past forecasts and past actuals?

Answer (score 1):

According to me, for model training we should always use the actual data, so that your prediction is always close to realty.

> **But in case if I have the prediction data as well,**
>
> 1. I will trained another model with the prediction data.
> 2. Analysis the outcome of the two models.
> 3. Identify the deviation between two outcomes.
> 4. Will use as threshold(variation) in future prediction.